# Нужна подсказка по слайдеру

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, слайдер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой вот слайдер. Проблема в том, что я немного не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы текст и тень на средней картинке отображались, а на остальных нет. Сам использую Owl-carousel, но с таким не сталкивался. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Обычно в слайдерах активный элемент имеет свой класс, типа .active (в owl именно такой). Ну и запрещайте показ текста и картинок (display: none; в css) на основании присутствия .active.

Comment: Это да, но когда элементов больше чем 1, то класс .active присваивается всем и выделить один врятли получится

Comment: С чего это "класс присваивается всем"? Вы посмотрите, как работает  owl слайдер, понаблюдайте за  изменениями классов, а потом перечитайте, что вы тут написали. В слайдере работает js, и элемент с классом .active всегда один, вне зависмости от общего их количества.